# How can I find the common overlaps in a set of time durations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, duration

I have a set of durations (using [moment-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range) but happy to use native code or something else) like this:

```
2018-06-19T09:00:00Z - 2018-06-19T10:00:00Z
2018-06-19T09:30:00Z - 2018-06-19T10:30:00Z
2018-06-19T09:30:00Z - 2018-06-19T11:00:00Z
2018-06-19T10:00:00Z - 2018-06-19T11:00:00Z
```

Which looks like:

```
09:00 ..+-+.................
        | |
09:30 ..| |..+-+..+-+.......
        | |  | |  | |
10:00 ..+-+..| |..| |..+-+..
             | |  | |  | |
10:30 .......+-+..| |..| |..
                  | |  | |
11:00 ............+-+..+-+..
```

And I want an algorithm to find the durations where at least 3 (or x) durations overlap. In the example above there is are two durations that meet this criteria:

```
2018-06-19T09:30:00Z - 2018-06-19T10:00:00Z
2018-06-19T10:00:00Z - 2018-06-19T10:30:00Z
```

I have spent ages trying to work this out, especially using *moment-range*, but I am totally flummoxed!

**Update**

Seeing as the question was downvoted, which I presume is because according to Stack Overflow suggestion "[it is] unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem in a way that can be properly addressed by answerers", I wanted to share what I have tried.

- I looped through all the ranges and worked out the overlaps with the other ranges, but I could not see how this array of new ranges could help me.
- On @hon2a's suggestion, I tried to work out the ranges where the range overlaps with other ranges at least 3 times but I think that is the crux of my problem. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "where all durations overlap at least X times"? Is it "where at least X ranges overlap"? The second "match" in your second code sample should likely be 10:00-10:30, not up until 13:00. Do the ranges always start & end on the hour or on X:30?

Comment: @hon2a - Sorry there was a typo which I have corrected. I also worded the question a bit better.. The ranges may start and end at arbitrary times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial algorithm is:

1. Create all combinations of 3 (or X) different ranges from the set.
2. For each combination, compute the intersection of the three.
3. Return a union of the intersections.

---

```
// ranges: Array<{ from: number, to: number }>, x: number
const combinations = _.combinations(ranges, x) // lodash.combinations
const intersections = combinations.map(combination => combination.reduce(
  (intersection, range) => ({
    from: Math.max(intersection.from, range.from),
    to: Math.min(intersection.to, range.to)
  })
  { from: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, to: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER }
)).filter(({ from, to }) => from < to)
// ... (union is trivial too)
```

---

*I've no idea if it can be done with lower time complexity, but since you haven't shared any info of what you've actually tried, I guess I should be voting to close rather than answering anyway.*

Comment: I was surprised for the votes to close the question as I thought it was reasonably well asked. Maybe I misunderstand the requirements of asking questions on SO and need to read the rules again. However, I did do step one of your suggestion but I found difficulty (using moment-range at least) to do step 2

Comment: @cubabit I'd assume the downvotes were because it's unclear where the problem is. I've no idea how `moment-range` API looks like, but computing range overlaps is trivial.

Comment: Without a clear description of what you tried and where you're failing, it looks like you're just using StackOverflow to do your homework assignment. On the off-chance this appearance is misleading I've added some pseudo-code to the answer.

Comment: Ah OK I can see your point of view but it just seems funny to me as I am not a student - I need this for a professional work problem. I think algorithms are just not my thing and I had wasted a day trying to work this one out. i appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful :)